# GET Multiple MySQL Rows, Form PHP Variables, and Put Into Json Encoded Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli, get

I am trying to GET different rows from different columns in php/mysql, and pack them into an array. I am able to successfully GET a jason encoded array back IF all values in the GET string match. However, if there is no match, the code echos 'no match', and without the array. I know this is because of the way my code is formatted. What I would like help figuring out, is how to format my code so that it just displays "null" in the array for the match it couldn't find.

**Here is my code:**

```
include '../db/dbcon.php';
$res = $mysqli->query($q1) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$q1]");
if ($res) {
if($res->num_rows === 0)
{
    echo json_encode($fbaddra);
}
else
{
    while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    if($_GET['a'] == "fbaddra") {
        if ($row['facebook'] === $_GET['facebook']) {
            $fbaddr = $row['addr'];

        } else {
            $fbaddr = null;
        }
        if ($row['facebookp'] === $_GET['facebookp']) {
                $fbpaddr = $row['addr'];

        } else {
            $fbpaddr = null;
        }
        $fbaddra = (array('facebook' => $fbaddr, 'facebookp' => $fbpaddr));
        echo json_encode($fbaddra);
    }
    }
}
$mysqli->close();
```

**UPDATE: The GET Request**

I would like the GET request below to return the full array, with whatever value that didn't match as 'null' inside the array.

```
domain.com/api/core/engine.php?a=fbaddra&facebook=username&facebookp=pagename
```

The GET above currently returns null.

Requests that work:

```
domain.com/api/core/engine.php?a=fbaddra&facebook=username or    domain.com/api/core/engine.php?a=fbaddra&facebookp=pagename
```

These requests return the full array with the values that match, or null for the values that don't.

**TL;DR**
I need assistance figuring out how to format code to give back the full array with a value of 'null' for no match found in a row.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. you cannot have `while(..) {... json_encode();}`. You will be outputting invalid json - json string has to be a MONOLITHIC entity. YOu cann't simply stack multiple json-encoded "things" next to each other and have them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather than assigning as 'null' assign null. Your full code as follows :

```
include '../db/dbcon.php';
$res = $mysqli->query($q1) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$q1]");
if ($res) {
if($res->num_rows === 0)
{
    echo json_encode('no match');
}
else
{
    while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    if($_GET['a'] == "fbaddra") {
        if ($row['facebook'] === $_GET['facebook']) {
            $fbaddr = $row['dogeaddr'];
                //echo json_encode($row['dogeaddr']);
        } else {
            $fpaddr = null;
        }
        if ($row['facebookp'] === $_GET['facebookp']) {
                $fbpaddr = $row['dogeaddr'];
                //echo json_encode($row['dogeaddr']);
        } else {
            $fbpaddr = null;
        }
        $fbaddra = (array('facebook' => $fbaddr, 'facebookp' => $fbpaddr));
        echo json_encode($fbaddra);
    }
    }
}
$mysqli->close();
```

You can even leave else part altogether.

Comment: If one or both of the values do not match in the GET string, it still returns only 'no match', instead of the full array with values that have no match as 'null'.

Comment: no match will only come if the code never entered else part. Is your else part working as expected. If you want to format if part as well you can use  $fbaddra = (array('facebook' => null, 'facebookp' => null));
        echo json_encode($fbaddra); in if part

Comment: I agree that the else statements need to be reformatted. However if I change `echo json_encode('no match');` to `echo json_encode($fbaddra);` then all I get back is null, and no array. Suggestions?

Comment: first create empty array for $fbaddra like `$fbaddra = (array('facebook' => null, 'facebookp' => null));` and then use `echo json_encode($fbaddra);`

Comment: Odd. I still get back only null, with the code above and your specified blank array values. Seems like the whole thing might need to be re-structured? Suggestions?

Comment: I was understanding your question differently, initiate both the variables to null at top ie before while and remove both the else part and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code in this fragment you not use same names for variables:

```
if ($row['facebook'] === $_GET['facebook']) {
            $fbaddr = $row['dogeaddr'];
                //echo json_encode($row['dogeaddr']);
        } else {
            $fpaddr = 'null';
        }
```

$fbaddr not is same as $fpaddr, this assign wrong result to if statement.

Comment: Fixed, and still gives only 'no match'. No array.

Comment: Replace: `echo json_encode('no match');` line to: `$fbaddra = (array('facebook' => 0, 'facebookp' => 0));
        echo json_encode($fbaddra);`

Comment: Putting esle $fbaddra = (array('facebook' => null, 'facebookp' => $fbpaddr)); instead of else echo null, for the else functions (with each else functions respective variables), still returns null on GET request. No array.

Answer (score 0):

It was the mysql query that was the problem.

For those who come across this, and need something similar, you'll need to format your query like this:

** MYSQL QUERY **

```
if ($_GET['PUTVALUEHERE']) {
    $g = $_GET['PUTVALUEHERE'];
    $gq = $mysqli->real_escape_string($g);
    $q1 = "SELECT * FROM `addrbook` WHERE `facebookp` = '".$gq."' OR `facebook` = '".$gq."'";
}
```

** PHP CODE **

```
if($_GET['PUTVALUEHERE']{
echo json_encode($row['addr']);
```

}